# How to print Yes/No after inputting all values?

Tags: python

```
input is :
        5
        P204BT
        X182YZ
        a216bc
        A216BC
        ABC216
```

but after every inputted value i call def _check and it prints Yes/No. How to make output after inputting all values, but not after each value?

```
def _check():
    Alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'H', 'K', 'M', 'O', 'P', 'T', 'X', 'Y']
    w1 = busId[0]
    n1, n2, n3 = busId[1], busId[2], busId[3]
    w2 = busId[4]
    w3 = busId[5]
    if w1 in Alphabet and w2 in Alphabet and w3 in Alphabet and n1.isnumeric() and n2.isnumeric() and n3.isnumeric():
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')

n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    busId = [x for x in input()]
    _check()
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways you could complete this code. The most simple solution in my opinion would be to take all the variables and put them into a list or an array. Then iterate through the entire list using a for loop and i to check if the values inside the list are what you want. This should allow the program to keep all the values together instead of reading them separately.